# Generating function and binomial coefficient

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

a) I have to find and expression for sequence of $b_n$ in terms of generating functions of the sequence of $a_n$
$$b_n = (-1)^{n}(n+1)a_0 +(-1)^{n-1}n a_1+...+(-1)2a_{n-1}+a_n$$ with $$a_n = a_{n-1} +8a_{n-2} -12a_{n-3} +25(-3)^{n-2} + 32n^2 -64$$

b) I have to use the result of a) to prove this identity
$${\beta \choose n} = \sum_{x = 0}^{n}(-1)^{x}(x+1) {\beta+2 \choose {n-x}}$$ with $\beta$ is a complex number

Please shed some lights. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Case a.)** We consider a generating function $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and are looking for a generating function $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> b_n&=(-1)^n(n+1)a_0+(-1)^{n-1}na_1+\cdots -2a_{n-1}+a_n\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1-k) a_k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We apply the *[Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n]A(z)=a_n
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain from (1):
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_n}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1-k) a_k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}(k+1) a_{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\left([z^k]\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right)\left([z^{n-k}]A(z)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^n]\frac{1}{(1+z)^{2}}A(z)}
> \end{align*}
>   and conclude the relation (1) in terms of generating functions is given as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(z)=\frac{A(z)}{(1+z)^2}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we change the order of summation by replacing the index $k$ with $n-k$.
- In (3) we use the series representation
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)z^k=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
  \end{align*}
  and apply the *Cauchy product formula*.

> **Case b.)** In order to show the binomial identity for $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{\beta}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{\beta+2}{n-k}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> we just need the relationsship  between $b_n$ and $a_n$ as stated in (1).
>   Here we are in a  situation as shown in (2) with $a_n=b_n$, namely
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}(k+1) a_{n-k}
> \end{align*}
>   This means that recalling the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and setting
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\beta+2}{k}z^k=(1+z)^{\beta+2}\\
> B(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\beta}{k}z^k=(1+z)^{\beta}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and we see the binomial identity (5) in terms of generating functions is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(1+z)^{\beta}=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}(1+z)^{\beta+2}}
> \end{align*}
>   which proves the claim.

Comment: Nice work as always.... +1

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Thanks for the nice comment and the credit. :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks so much. This is really nice work :) . I have just one thing to ask that how could you quickly arrive to the setting (the identity) of A(z) and B(z) for case b) ?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  and at the very last blue line, do you mean that A(z) = B(z)/ $(1+z)^2$ ?

Comment: @Thy: You're welcome. I've added a hint (binomial series) and corrected the typo regarding your last comment. Good review. :-)